# Slow numpy element by element array division

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division

I have the following code:

```
p_1_test = np.divide(lhs_n, np.array(range(1,n+1)))
```

Where `lhs_n` is a numpy array of length `n`.  This currently takes about 17 seconds vs 0.25 seconds looping for approx n=48000.  Anyone know why this is so slow, and how to vectorize it in a way that will speed it up?

Comment: It may take a while to create the intermediate `range`.  Did you try using `np.arange` instead to create the array directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.array(range(...))` has to first create a `range`, which in Python 2 is a regular list.  This means it will have to create a 48,000-element list just as a preliminary to creating the numpy array.

Instead, try using `np.arange(1, n+1)` to directly create a numpy array with a certain range of values, avoiding the creation of an intermediate list.